# Push notification in expo project

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Currently in my company we have native applications (ios and android), and we are replacing the native apps with one react-native app using Expo. The native apps are configured to use push notifications, and the backend is configured too, but we can NOT make changes in the backend (it was made by another company and it is in production, and asking for changes could cost a lot to my company), so we have to use the same configurations in the new react-native app.

My problem is that using expo I need to make changes in the backend in order to use notifications. The only other solution is to eject the application and configure the ios/android apps manually.

My question is: Is there a way to continue using expo (in development, because it's awesome) with having the ability to configure ios/android apps manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is 2 kinds of eject:

- Eject the application to a plain React Native app using the commande `eject`.
- Eject to expoKit using the command `exp detach` or `eject` and then choosing to use ExpoKit. Here we can still use the Expo platform with having the ability to manually manage the ios/android projects

More information in the following links:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md#ejecting-to-expokit